# Highstocks: How to define the span colors of a line instead of the individual line color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am creating a Gantt Chart using Highstocks(compare multiple series).
1. I want to have the First span color to be Red, the second Blue and third Green.
How can I do the same?
2. how can i set the tooltip to show the values of all the points on the line instead of all points at the time.
3. How to fix y-axis and it should add scroll as values increase.

Please check the Gantt Chart Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/z98se/1/).

```
var partNumber="2724070125R Planned,2724070125RActual,5511822432R Planned,5511822432RActual";
    var partNum = partNumber.split(",");
var ganttData = [
[[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,07),1], [Date.UTC(2013,11-1,29),1], [Date.UTC(2013,11-1,30),1]],
 [[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,20),1.25],Date.UTC(2013,11-1,21),1.25],Date.UTC(2013,12-1,21),1.25]],
[[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,13),2],[Date.UTC(2013,12-1,10),2],[Date.UTC(2014,02-1,14),2]],
[[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,21),2.25],[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,21),2.25],[Date.UTC(2013,11-1,30),2.25]]];
$( document ).ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            var seriesOptions = [],
                yAxisOptions = [],
                seriesCounter = 0,
                names = partNum,
                colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;          
                   var data=ganttData;                         
             $(function () {                     
             $.each(names, function(i, name) {
                      seriesOptions[i] = {

                       // name: data[i][1],
                         name:name,
                         step:true,
                        data: data[i]                         
                    };

                    // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
                    // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
                    seriesCounter++;

                    if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
                        createChart();
                    }
                });
            });

            // create the chart when all data is loaded
            function createChart() {
                Highcharts.setOptions({

                    global: {
                        useUTC: false
                    }
                });

               $('#ganttChart').highcharts('StockChart', {
                    chart: {
                    },
                    title: {
            text: 'PPAP Cumulative Status'
        },

                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 4
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',                            ordinal: false //this sets the fixed time formats

                    },
                    yAxis: {

                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 2,
                            color: 'silver'
                        }],
               min:0                     },

                    plotOptions: {
                   series: {
                                lineWidth: 3,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        lineWidth: 3
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    },

                    tooltip: {

                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                        valueDecimals: 0
                    },

                    series: seriesOptions,
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    }

                });
            }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can set for series only one color. Here:

```
         $.each(names, function(i, name) {
                  seriesOptions[i] = {
                     name: name,
                     step: true,
                     data: data[i],
                     color: 'yourColor'                        
                   };
         ...
         });
```

2) In tooltip, you have access to series via `this.points[0].series.data` etc. So you can get all points.

3)  Scroll is not supported.

Comment: I tried to access series by `tooltip: {pointFormat:'{series.name}:<b>{this.points[0].series.data}</b><br/>',..}` the link is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeXU/) but its not working am I doing it right?

Comment: Thanks it worked.... Another question: Scroll on Y-axis is not supported in Highstocks. Is it possible in highcharts? If yes can you quote some reference.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't have any kind of scrollbar.

Comment: Pawel thanks for the information,.. though problem is not resolved.

Comment: Pardon? Your question is about colors and you said my answer resolved your issue. Regarding your second question, this is not supported.

Comment: I didn't say that your answer resolved my issue but it closed the issue as it is not supported.